# How can I replicate this calculation in a vectorized way python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops, multidimensional-array

I have this calculation that I am trying to vectorize, the problem I am having is there are additional loops that need to be added and it takes very long to loop through 300 000 + customers.

current example I am trying to vectorize:

```
matrix = np.arange(250).reshape(10,5,5)
customer1= np.array([0,0,100,0,0])
output = customer1
results = []
for arr in matrix[5:9]:
    output = output@arr
    results.append(output)
```

I have tried using the following but the output isnt the same:

`from numpy.linalg import multi_dot`

`result_1= multi_dot([customer1, (matrix[5:9])])`

Comment: you can use: `results = np.vsplit(matrix[5:9,2]*100,1)`

Comment: Just noticed that behind the hood, `vsplit` call `array_split` that use a for loop to split each row of the 2D matrix. Do you really need a list of array as output instead of a 2D matrix ?

Answer (score 0):

You can expand `customers` in the middle dimension to make its shape `(no_customers,1,5)` and `arr` in the first dimension to make its shape `(1,5,5)`, then take advantage of numpy broadcast (on the first dimension) to do matmul for all customers at once:

```
matrix = np.arange(250).reshape(10,5,5)
customers = np.array([[0,0,100,0,0], [0,100,0,0,0]])
output = customers[:,None,:]  # shape (2,1,5)
results = []
for arr in matrix[5:9]:
    output = output@arr[None,:]
    results.append(output.squeeze())
```

Results:

```
[array([[13500, 13600, 13700, 13800, 13900],
        [13000, 13100, 13200, 13300, 13400]]),
 array([[10965000, 11033500, 11102000, 11170500, 11239000],
        [10565000, 10631000, 10697000, 10763000, 10829000]]),
 array([[1682840408, 1738350408, 1793860408, 1849370408, 1904880408],
        [1308090408, 1361575408, 1415060408, 1468545408, 1522030408]]),
 array([[  838285456,  1217652904,  1597020352,  1976387800, -1939212048],
        [-1865973312,   914361432,  -600271120, -2114903672,   665431072]])]
```

In each array, first row is result of first customer, second row is result of second customer, and so on.